# Adding records onAfterCreate

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table in Google App Maker, which is called Prerequisites. I have another one called courses. Basically, when I add a record to courses, I want it to automatically add the course name as a record to the prerequisites table. This is what i have in the onAfterCreate event in the courses table:

```
var prereqs = app.models.Prerequisites.newRecord();
record.Course = prereqs.Prerequisites;
app.saveRecords([record]);
```

Nothing is happening though. No error, but I am not getting a new record in the prerequisites table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I put this code in the datasource query script:

```
var courseQuery = app.models.Courses.newQuery();
var run = courseQuery.run();
var results = run.map(function(course) {
var prereq = app.models.Prerequisites.newRecord();
  prereq.Prerequisites = course.Course;
  return prereq;
});
return results;
```